# Switching VMs and The Static IP

Tags: linux, centos, rackspace-cloud

I recently changed the VM im running CentOS on to a new one, and everything works fine. Except that recently i face problems starting gogs, a self hosted git server, with the following error. As the erorr states, there is a problem with ip, apparently my old VM ip is still hardcoded somewhere in the VM, and this is the old ip im getting below.

Are there any linux configuration i should be aware of to update my new ip on the VM, knowing that ifconfig gets me the right ip, the new one.

[image]

Comment: The gogs configuration refers to the old IP address. You need to find that bit of configuration and fix/change it.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried checking custom/conf/app.ini and conf/app.ini but found no traces of my old ip address, where else i should look?

Comment: Check the `/etc/hosts` file on the system and make sure that `host <domain>` and `dig <domain>` from the new system return the correct IP address.

Comment: @EtanReisner ure the man. Can you please post it as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Etan Reisner, I checked the /etc/hosts file on the system and made sure that host  and dig  from the new system return the correct IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://gogs.io/docs/advanced/configuration_cheat_sheet.html

You'll need to edit the file `custom/conf/app.ini` and change the value of `HTTP_ADDR`

Comment: well the value is a domain, which points to my new ip, no traces of my old ip in the file

Comment: If you want to add a bit about the hosts file this will be a complete answer (see the comments on the post). I couldn't have pointed the OP at those config files to have figured this out on my own so you have the answer on this one.